# Obtener datos de la consola de html de firefox con selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, java-8, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

buenas a tod@s, estoy intentado visualizar u obtener todos los errores de la consola html con selenium java, he podido conseguir para chrome y edge pero con firefox y safari no he podido. Este es el código:

```
public void logConsoleChrome(WebDriver driver) {


            // Get browser console logs
            LogEntries logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
            // Find the last entry containing "Server call failed"
            LogEntry lastErrorEntry = null;
            for (LogEntry entry : logEntries) {
                if (entry.getMessage().contains("Error en la llamada al servidor")) {
                    lastErrorEntry = entry;
                }
            }
            // Procesar la entrada del log si se encuentra un error
            if (lastErrorEntry != null) {
                System.out.println("dentro_server_ 1");
                String server = null;
                // Print the last error entry if any were found
                if (lastErrorEntry.getMessage().contains("Error en la llamada al servidor")) {
                    server = lastErrorEntry.getMessage().replaceAll("[\"\\\\]", "");

                } else {
                    System.out.println("No se encontraron errores en la llamada al servidor en el registro del navegador.");
                }

                List<String> typeMessageServer = new ArrayList<>();

                if (server.replace("\"", "").contains("{codigoMostrar:")) {
                    // Extract codeShow and next number
                    int indexCodeShow = server.indexOf("codigoMostrar:") + "codigoMostrar:".length();
                    int indexComa = server.indexOf(",", indexCodeShow);
                    String codePoint = server.substring(indexCodeShow, indexComa);

                    int indexNumber = server.indexOf("text:", indexComa) + "text:".length();
                    int indexNumberEnd = server.indexOf(",", indexNumber);
                    String numberMore = server.substring(indexNumber, indexNumberEnd);

                    typeMessageServer.add(codePoint);
                    typeMessageServer.add(numberMore);
                    System.out.println("dentro_server_2");
                }
                // visualiza un logger de info
                ClassInjector.getSharedContent().getCurrentScenario().get().log("Code number: " + typeMessageServer.get(0) + " | Type message: " + typeMessageServer.get(1));
            }

    }
```

Y el error que me da es cuando llega a `driver.manage().lgos().get(Logtype.BROWSER); -> Method threw 'org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException' exception.  /// HTTP method not allowed Command duration or timeout: 1.01 seconds`. Había añadido un tiempo de espera por el http for timeout pero no consigo el resultado esperado.
Hay otra manera que pueda obtener estos resultados, según la guia de https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/console/log_static si permite hacer logs pero no es mi caso.
Gracias!